# jQuery - Separating boolean cases into methods

Tags: jquery

I feel like this is fairly simple but i'm not familiar enough with jQuery to understand. I have two functions and if setHeader is true run the click handler. If setHeader is false then I want to do another action. I'm trying to seperate out the true false cases into two different methods but have no idea how I would do that. Anybody have any ideas? New to jQuery so code samples would really be appreciated.

```
function setHeader(set) {
     if (set){
        $('.header').on('click', function(event){
             if($('.header').find('.submenu *').is(event.target)) return;
             if($(this).hasClass('active')) collapseItem($(this)); else expandItem($(this));
        });
     } else {
         //do something
     }
}

function init() {
    if ( $(window).width() <= 400) { 
        setHeader(true);
    } else {
        setHeader(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot just replace `setHeader(true)` with `setHeaderNewVersion()` and `setHeader(false)` with `doSomethingElse()`?

Comment: @Thilo I'm kind of confused. Anyway you could post a code sample pretty new to jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
function setHeader() {
        $('.header').on('click', function(event){
             if($('.header').find('.submenu *').is(event.target)) return;
             if($(this).hasClass('active')) collapseItem($(this)); else expandItem($(this));
        });    
}

function falseStatement(){
    console.log(false);
}

function init() {
    if ( $(window).width() <= 400) { 
        setHeader();
    } else {
        falseStatement();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Although this isn't really separating out the true and false cases into two different methods.

Comment: You are basically calling two identical if statements, although one is in another function?

Answer (score 0):

```
($(window).width() <= 400) ? setHeader() : falseStatement();
```